# GroupBy - is this expected behavior?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have simple EAV'ish scenario where `User` can be in multiple `Usergroup` and `Usergroup` can have multiple `Field`. I select user, select all his usergroups and then show the fields.

Problem is that I want not to show fields with duplicate `Key` property.

## Current situation

```
Fields = user.Usergroups
    .SelectMany(x => x.UsergroupFields)
    .Select(field => new
    {
        field.Key
    })
```

Product

```
"Fields": [
  {
    "Key": "field 1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "field 1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "field 2"
  }
]
```

As you can see I have multiple `field 1`, I want to remove duplicates based on `Key` property. I tried to do `GroupBy()` but it is doing something weird.

## GroupBy()

```
Fields = user.Usergroups
    .SelectMany(x => x.UsergroupFields)
    .GroupBy(field => field.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .Select(field => new
    {
        field.Key
    })
```

Results in

```
"Fields": [
  {
    "Key": "field 1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "field 1"
  }
]
```

It seems that GroupBy() is doing complete opposite of what I want to achieve.

Comment: You take the first *group* not the first item in each group. `GroupBy(...).Select(x=>x.First()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Fields = user.Usergroups
             .SelectMany(x => x.UsergroupFields)
             .GroupBy(field => field.Key)
             .Select(g=>g.First());
```

`GroupBy` also has an overload taking 2 arguments which can be applied in this case:

```
Fields = user.Usergroups
             .SelectMany(x => x.UsergroupFields)
             .GroupBy(field=>field.Key, (key, g)=>g.First());
```